Implementing Custom Actions for Content Types in Umbraco 14
I need to upgrade an existing Umbraco 13 website to Umbraco 14. One of the significant changes in Umbraco 14 is the introduction of a new backoffice, which requires modifications to existing backoffice extensions.
In my project, I use custom menu items that are tied to specific content types in the content section. In Umbraco 13, I implemented this functionality using the code below. However, the registration of these menu items has changed in Umbraco 14.
Based on the official documentation, it appears I need to register a "Sidebar Context Menu" in Umbraco 14. Unfortunately, I haven't found a clear example that demonstrates how to replicate the functionality I had in Umbraco 13 using the new approach.
I’m looking for a complete example or guidance on how to achieve this in Umbraco 14. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
Here is the code I used in Umbraco 13:
public class BackofficeMenu : IComposer
{
    public void Compose(IUmbracoBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.AddNotificationHandler<MenuRenderingNotification, MenuRenderingNotificationHandler>();
    }
}

public class MenuRenderingNotificationHandler : INotificationHandler<MenuRenderingNotification>
{
    private readonly IPublishedContentQueryAccessor _publishedContentQueryAccessor;

    public MenuRenderingNotificationHandler(IPublishedContentQueryAccessor publishedContentQueryAccessor)
    {
        _publishedContentQueryAccessor = publishedContentQueryAccessor;
    }

    public void Handle(MenuRenderingNotification notification)
    {
        if (notification.TreeAlias == "content")
        {
            _publishedContentQueryAccessor.TryGetValue(out var publishedContentQuery);
            var content = publishedContentQuery?.Content(notification.NodeId);

            if (content != null && content.ContentType.Alias == "frontpage")
            {
                var smsMessageMenuItem = new MenuItem("smsMessageMenuItem", "SMS messages");
                smsMessageMenuItem.AdditionalData.Add("actionView", "/path/to/my/custom/view");
                notification.Menu.Items.Add(smsMessageMenuItem);
            }
        }
    }
}


